# Getting a list of suffixes from the company names

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame df with a column name - Company. Few examples of the company names are: ABC Inc., XYZ Gmbh, PQR Ltd, JKL Limited etc. I want a list of all the suffixes (Inc.,Gmbh, Ltd., Limited etc). Please notice that suffix length is always different. There might be companies without any suffix, for example: Apple. I need a complete list of all suffixes from the all the company names, keeping only unique suffixes in the list.

How do I accomplish this task?

Comment: What is your criterion for something being a suffix? i.e., How do you know that `Limited` in `JKL Limited` is a suffix, but `CarPhoneHouse` in `The CarPhoneHouse` is not?

Comment: @Anaphory  That is my challenge. I want to remove all the suffixes from the company name. So probably the word after the last space in the complete string would be the suffix. I want only the unique list. I can manually take out the words like CarPhoneHouse. Please suggest if you have a better way.

Comment: As a side note: the full company's name is "Apple Inc.".

Comment: @KlausD. You are correct. But my data has a lot of errors. I have just taken an example to show that there might be many companies without any suffix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
In [36]: df
Out[36]:
         Company
0         Google
1      Apple Inc
2  Microsoft Inc
3       ABC Inc.
4       XYZ Gmbh
5        PQR Ltd
6    JKL Limited

In [37]: df.Company.str.extract(r'\s+([^\s]+$)', expand=False).dropna().unique()
Out[37]: array(['Inc', 'Inc.', 'Gmbh', 'Ltd', 'Limited'], dtype=object)
```

or ignoring punctuation:

```
In [38]: import string

In [39]: df.Company.str.replace('['+string.punctuation+']+','')
Out[39]:
0           Google
1        Apple Inc
2    Microsoft Inc
3          ABC Inc
4         XYZ Gmbh
5          PQR Ltd
6      JKL Limited
Name: Company, dtype: object

In [40]: df.Company.str.replace('['+string.punctuation+']+','').str.extract(r'\s+([^\s]+$)', expand=False).dropna().unique()
Out[40]: array(['Inc', 'Gmbh', 'Ltd', 'Limited'], dtype=object)
```

export result into Excel file:

```
data = df.Company.str.replace('['+string.punctuation+']+','').str.extract(r'\s+([^\s]+$)', expand=False).dropna().unique()
res = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Comp_suffix'])
res.to_excel(r'/path/to/file.xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: This looks great @MaxU This gives me output like - array([u'Inc', u'Management', u'ZAO', ..., u'Ltd'], dtype=object. Probably 'u' represents unicode. What changes can I make int he above code to get rid of this 'u'. Also, because my data is huge, is there a way to get this output in a more readable format, probably excel.

Comment: @user6461192, you can simply ignore those `u` - it's just a representation of unicode strings. I've extended my answer with `export to Excel` - please check

Answer (score 2):

You can use [cleanco](https://github.com/psolin/cleanco) Python library for that, it has a [list](https://github.com/psolin/cleanco/blob/master/termdata.py) of all possible suffixes inside. E.g. it contains all the examples you provided (Inc, Gmbh, Ltd, Limited).

So you can take the suffixes from the library and use them as a dictionary to search in your data, e.g.:

```
import pandas as pd
company_names = pd.Series(["Apple", "ABS LLC", "Animusoft Corp", "A GMBH"])
suffixes = ["llc", "corp", "abc"]  # take from cleanco source code
found = [any(company_names.map(lambda x: x.lower().endswith(' ' + suffix))) for suffix in suffixes]
suffixes_found = [suffix for (suffix, suffix_found) in zip(suffixes, found) if suffix_found]
print suffixes_found  # outputs ['llc', 'corp']
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want the last word of the Company name, assuming the company has a name more than one word long?

```
set(name_list[-1] for name_list in map(str.split, company_names) if len(name_list) > 1)
```

The `[-1]` gets the last word.  `str.split` splits on spaces.  I've never used pandas, so getting `company_names` might be the hard part of this.

Comment: I have figured out how to take out the last word, but I am not able to add the condition of that length of each company should be greater than 1 word. Here you go -  df["suffix"] = df["Company"].str.split().str[-1]

Comment: Is `df['Company']` all the names?  In that case you can put it where I have `company_names` above

Comment: It gives me below errors if I do so - TypeError: descriptor 'split' requires a 'str' object but received a 'unicode'

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: Encodings are weird in 2.  Maybe do `map(lambda x: str(x).split(), company_names)` instead?  I admit I don't have much experience with 2

Answer (score 0):

This only adds the suffixes when the company name has more than one word as you required.

```
company_names = ["Apple", "ABS LLC", "Animusoft Corp"]
suffixes = [name.split()[-1] for name in company_names if len(name.split()) > 1]
```

Now having into account that this doesn't cover the unique requirement.
This doesn't cover that you can have a company named like "Be Smart" and "Smart" is not a suffix but part of the name. However this takes care of the unique requirement:

```
company_names = ["Apple", "ABS LLC", "Animusoft Corp", "BBC Corp"]
suffixes = []
for name in company_names:
    if len(name.split()) > 1 and name.split()[-1] not in suffixes:      
        suffixes.append(name.split()[-1])
```